# How to manage different "project branches" with DevOps

Tags: version-control, devops, branch

I am currently working on a project and in this moment we have a Release Candidate, which is supposed to go under an official V&V and then it will undergo a FDA submission (medical devices Software).
At the same time, we need to go ahead with another branch of the same project, adding some features, changing some of the requirements for the features that now are going under V&V, removing some of them.
This means that we will need to add, edit, delete some of our Requirements in DevOps to be aligned with the new features, but we also need to continue managing the requirements that are now valid for the Release Candidate under V&V, even if some of them will not be valid anymore in the new branch.

What would be the best choice to manage this situation with devOps?
In general, how to manage a version that starts from a certain point in the project and follows a partially different path with slight or heavy differences in the requirements?
What we would need is some kind of "versioning" of all the work items (requirements, test cases etc) we have currently in devOps. Is that possible?

Thank you!

Comment: It's a broad question but here are some of my prospectives on the subject: https://worklifenotes.com/2020/03/04/microservices-combinatorial-explosion-of-versions/ and https://worklifenotes.com/2019/03/21/devops-kpis-measuring-distance-between-latest-and-greatest-and-oldest-production-version/

The solution I'm proposing currently is going with bundles - https://worklifenotes.com/2020/11/15/devops-bundles-new-name-of-the-game/ - which are supported in Reliza Hub.

Finally, it's a long subject - feel free to join our Discord channel to discuss more: https://discord.gg/UTxjBf9juQ